# R split a text column based second occurrence of the seperator

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following 1 column data frame:

```
Column
XXX_513_TEXT
XXX_513
XXX_493_TEXT
XXX_493
XXX_589
```

which I want to split-out into 2 columns shown below:

```
Column1     Column2
XXX_513     TEXT
XXX_513      
XXX_493     TEXT
XXX_493     
XXX_589
```

I tried the following `seperate()` function from the `tidyr` package but the split is made on the first `_` after the XXX.

```
 separate(DataFrame, Column, c("Column1","Column2"), sep = "_")
```

How can I specify that I want to split on the second occurrence of `_`, if exists, and therefore achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_` only if they are preceded by a number:

```
separate(df, column, into = c("a", "b"), sep = "(?<=[0-9])_")
        a    b
1 XXX_513 TEXT
2 XXX_513 <NA>
3 XXX_493 TEXT
4 XXX_493 <NA>
5 XXX_589 <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks @sindri_baldur. I've added `fill="right"` to fix the warnings:
`separate(df, column, into = c("a", "b"), sep = "(?<=[0-9])_", fill="right")`